# Same line display option in Idempiere 7.1 custom window does not work

Tags: idempiere

FreeBSD-12.1p10 (jail)
PostgreSQL-11.8
Idempiere 7.1

I am following the customization tutorial found in the Compiere3.6 Cookbook (making the necesary adjustments for the current version of Idempiere).  I cannot get two fields to appear on the same line in the custom window.  The first field is *start_time*, the second field is *end_time*.  The *end_time* field is next in sequence to the *start_time* field.  The *end_time* field has the *Same Line* option checked.

However, *start_time* and *end_time* are each on their own line when the window is displayed. I made other changes to these two fields to display only time instead of `date+time` and those changes are reflected in the window display.  But they remain on separate lines.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the approach from Compiere 3.6 to distribute fields in windows is very basic, it just allows to have two columns of fields, and the *Same Line* flag was intended to allow a field to appear next to the first.

In iDempiere, since version 1.0, the concept to manage the fields was extended like a configurable grid with the values of *X Position* and *Column Span*.

You can find more information about that in the wiki page [Form Layout](https://wiki.idempiere.org/en/NF1.0_FormLayout).

Configuring windows with that pair of values is not easy manually, so a WISIWYG editor is also implemented, it is called the [Tab Editor](https://wiki.idempiere.org/en/NF1.0_TabEditor)